# communicate Common Lisp with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, common-lisp

I want to make an application using java and clisp. Is it possible to call a clisp function from eclipse and return the result of this function to a method in eclipse?

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking. If you need Java interopability use ABCL. If you want to use eclipse as a lisp IDE I believe there are lisp plug ins available, though I have never used them

Comment: yes, I'm looking for interoperability. I"ll check ABCL, thanks.

Comment: and for a Common Lisp Eclipse plugin see Dandelion: https://github.com/Ragnaroek/dandelion/

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that can make lisp interact with Java, for example [CL+J](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-plus-j/) is one and [Foil](http://foil.sourceforge.net/) is another. Note though both have limitations and aren't well developed. ABCL maybe a better solution but then you'll have to use specifically that implementation, while the other 2 libraries above offer portability. If you're not bound to only common lisp, there are scheme implementations too like Kawa and the older Jscheme that may be interesting.